# Case statement evaluating class not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, logic, switch-statement

I have some logic in my Rails application that checks the class type of my current_user variable:

```
logger.debug current_user.class # => Instructor
logger.debug current_user.class == Instructor # => true
case current_user.class
  when Admin
    logger.debug "Admin"
  when Student
    logger.debug "Student"
  when Instructor
    logger.debug "Instructor"
  else
    logger.debug "Guest"
end #=> "Guest"
```

Despite `Instructor` being the class type (as indicated in comments) it seems the case statement always evaluates the else fall-back. Can somebody explain why? Just to give a little background, I'm implementing an STI user model setup using Devise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `case curent_user` not `current_user.class`.

Your `case` statement is cross checking the class of `current_user.class` which is `Object` which falls through your case statement.

Secondly, please note that instead of the `case` you could have done:

```
logger.debug current_user.class.name
```

Comment: Thanks that worked - I didn't know it checked class by default.

Comment: The class of `current_user.class` is `Class`, not `Object`.